# Are the colors of this two comments different?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, comments

http://i64.tinypic.com/21l7uw2.png

These are the comments from the question [What is “relatively uniform resonant frequency”?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/315403/41634). I'm pretty sure that the colors are different, maybe their brightness. Is this normal?

I use Windows 7, with updated Firefox. I do install the [Stack Overflow Extras (SOX)](https://stackapps.com/q/6091/29559) script, but there is no option in it allow changing the comments' color. I notice that this is universal, every section of comments in every question or answer in every Stack Exchange site has this behavior.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. The comments look the same color to me. What OS and browser are you using? If you try another one, do you still see the color difference? Are you able to open your browser's developer tools and check the actual CSS color used for each comment's text?

Comment: The first one seems to be true black, and the second one rich black. Looks like a bug to me, but it may be on your end. I cant reproduce it either.

Comment: No repro for me as well.

Comment: I used a colour picker tool to get the colour from the fonts and they are the exact same over here,`#000000`.

Comment: I see them as slightly different. But not different enough that I think this really needs to be addressed

Comment: I've checked the CSS styles of the comments and they are exactly the same. But I saved your image, I checked with a lupe and yes, they have really different color. My first tip was that it is a subpixel rendering problem, but it is not. Aren't you using win10 or/and explorer/edge browsers? I've faced similar problems multiple times with them.

Comment: Please provide browser and OS information (names and versions) - is it happening with different browsers or just one?

Comment: Does this still reproduce if you remove the SOX script? Does it happen with other browsers? Latest firefox on Windows 10 doesn't repro this for me.

Comment: @Oded ohh it turns out to be the SOX script.

Comment: Funny, I don't have the SOX script, use chrome on windows 10, and still I see these as different colours

Comment: @Oded, you may want to ask Jim more

Comment: @Jim - do you have any other user scripts/stylesheets, add-ons, plugins, extensions or such? If you do, does this still happen when they are turned off?

Comment: BTW 1. In the HNQ queue, 2. in drop-down menus, or 3. on the front page of [MO.SE](http://mathoverflow.net/) the blue titles become violet if you have clicked them, i.e. the system marks threads as read. Perhaps Phys.SE front page titles should implement the same feature?

Comment: @Qmechanic isn't that the browsers who change the color, not the web?

Comment: @Ooker: Yes, it goes away if one clears one's browser history. But the chosen colors seems to be mostly by web design.

Comment: @Oded according to the SOX's dev, [the script does not touch the comments](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/issues/262#issuecomment-284063876)

Comment: @Ooker - be that as it may, you have a smoking gun. Disabling the script fixed your issue, enabling it brings it back.

Comment: @Oded ah, I just think that you may want to know more about it.

Comment: @Oded I have chatjax, but that wasn't on at the time. I also havre some standard chrome extensions like mail checker and adblock. But nothing that would touch the comments. It's funny because this is the first time I've seen a set of comments as different colours

Comment: @Jim - that's very odd. *Something* is changing the comment colours, and the likely reason is an extension/add-on/plugin. Disabling all of these and trying them back on one at a time should pinpoint the culprit.

Comment: @Oded tried disabling all extensions as well as opening the page in incognito mode. It's always the same: a different colour. I have no reason for believing this, but I suspect there may be something here to do with the settings of the person that posted the comment

Comment: Hang on, I just tried opening it in firefox, it was the same colour. Then I switched back to chrome without closing my firefox or chrome windows and it was fixed in chrome. This is confusing